# React Apollo Client - modify query data before it goes to cache

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

Is there a way to modify query response data before it is saved in the internal cache?
I'm using apollo hooks, but this question is relevant to any of front-end approaches using apollo client (HOC & Components as well).

```
const { data, updateQuery } = useQuery(QUERY, {
  onBeforeDataGoesToCache: originalResponseData => {
    // modify data before it is cached? Can I have something like this? 
    return modifiedData;
  }
});
```

Obviously `onBeforeDataGoesToCache` does not exist, but that's exactly the behavior I'm looking for. There's an `updateQuery` function in the result, which basically does what is needed, but in the wrong time. I'm looking for something to work as a hook or a middleware inside the query mutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want [Afterware](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http/#afterware-data-manipulation) which, much like Middleware that allows operations before the request is made, allows you to manipulate data in the response e.g.

```
const modifyDataLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(operation).map(response => {
    // Modify response.data...

    return response;
  });
});

// use with apollo-client
const link = modifyDataLink.concat(httpLink);
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Didn't expect it to be in `apollo-link-http`. Thank you!